# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@emotion/styled/base' when running story book

Tags: reactjs, storybook, emotion

I recently installed Storybook to my project

Dependencies and Dev Dependencies below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^11.0.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.1.2",
    "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/jest": "^11.1.0",
    "@emotion/styled-base": "^11.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.15",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.15",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.15",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.15",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.4.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-emotion": "^11.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-require-context-hook": "^1.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-prop-type-error": "^1.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.4",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "standard-version": "^9.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.15.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
```

I built a simple button component that uses `@emotion/styled` for styling. I would like to add a story for this button, however, when running `npm run storybook` i get the following error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@emotion/styled/base' in '/directory/to/Button'
```

This is what I am importing inside my button component:

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { useTheme } from '@emotion/react';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: ${({ fontSize }) => fontSize};
`;
```

This is happening to other components that use `@emotion/styled` as well. Am i missing an extra dependency or do I need to add any presets to .babelrc file?

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["require-context-hook"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel", "@emotion"]
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use storybook for the first time, and this is the first thing I hit.  If you find a solution, please share.

Answer (score 24):

This is an issue caused by the break name change of emotion 11. So far storybook internally is still looking for the v10 names to integrate emotion packages. So you would have 2 options before storybook fixed it:

A. Downgrade to emotion 10.

B. A workaround:

```
// .storybook/main.js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");

function getPackageDir(filepath) {
  let currDir = path.dirname(require.resolve(filepath));
  while (true) {
    if (fs.existsSync(path.join(currDir, "package.json"))) {
      return currDir;
    }
    const { dir, root } = path.parse(currDir);
    if (dir === root) {
      throw new Error(
        `Could not find package.json in the parent directories starting from ${filepath}.`
      );
    }
    currDir = dir;
  }
}

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    "../stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../components/**/*.stories.@(ts|tsx|mdx)",
  ],
  addons: ["@storybook/addon-links", "@storybook/addon-essentials"],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    return merge(config, {
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          "@emotion/core": getPackageDir("@emotion/react"),
          "@emotion/styled": getPackageDir("@emotion/styled"),
          "emotion-theming": getPackageDir("@emotion/react"),
        },
      },
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: This worked for me in an NX workspace project.

Comment: Many thanks this has fixed the issue for me, is there a thread I can follow to know when Storybook fixes this issue do you know?

Comment: @MatthewBarnden not sure but I think I haven't met with such issue recently when setting new project with emotion and storybook...so I was guessing they have fixed already... Have they?

Comment: FYI you can replace `getPackageDir()` with `require.resolve()`

Comment: This doesn't work for me and my nx project

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue. The `@emotion/babel-plugin` needs to be enabled as the top most plugin in your .babelrc file.

you have: `"plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel", "@emotion"]`

should be: `"plugins": [ "@emotion", "react-hot-loader/babel"]`

Also, be sure to take a look at the instructions from emotion below

https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/babel-plugin

I'm using emotion libraries:
`"@emotion/react": "^11.1.5"`
`"@emotion/styled": "^11.1.5"`
`"@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.2.0"`

Comment: This does not work for me. I don't even have react-hot-loader/babel installed

Comment: It's not working for me the above re-arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the recent version of styled components with React. I resolved it by installing the babel plugin styled components

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components`

Then I re-ran the app and it worked again. I hope this will help you in your problem.

Comment: The question is about emotion not `styled-components`.

Comment: I know I just wanted to share that had similar problem with styled-components and I fixed re-installing or changing babel. Sorry!!

Answer (score -1):

To follow up with yan's comment.

You could write the webpack config as follow for better readability:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../stories/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../components/**/*.stories.@(ts|tsx|mdx)',
  ],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      '@emotion/core': getPackageDir('@emotion/react'),
      '@emotion/styled': getPackageDir('@emotion/styled'),
      'emotion-theming': getPackageDir('@emotion/react'),
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: This answer falls flat because it is not known what you intend by `getPackageDir`, is this something that builds the path from the root of the project? Something with `require()`, `import()`, etc.